# bootstrap remove active class from radio type btn-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a bootstrap btn-group that I want to give the user the ability to select one or no options from. Everything on the data end is working great except for the fact that I can not remove the active class from the button when the user turns it off.

```
<div class="btn-group" id="localRasterBG" data-toggle = "buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default localBaseMaps" id="btnLand Cover" data-layerName="Land Cover" onclick="rasterButtonClick(event)" >
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnLandCover" autocomplete="off"> Land Cover
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default localBaseMaps" data-layerName="Elevation" onclick="rasterButtonClick(event)">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnElevation" autocomplete="off"> Elevation
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default localBaseMaps active" id="btnPopulation" data-layerName="Population" onclick="rasterButtonClick(event)">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnLandScan" autocomplete="off"> Population
    </label>
</div>
```

However, I am unable to remove the "active' class with javascript:

```
function rasterButtonClick(e){
        e.target.removeClass("active");
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks, Tyler

Comment: Maybe you want checkboxes instead of radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

`removeClass` is a `jQuery` function, you need to change it to:

```
 $(e.target).removeClass("active");
```

Comment: I gave it a try but nothing happened.

Comment: I ran a console.log before and after the removeClass function and it did confirm that the class was removed.

Comment: However, the button still looks active.